# Get sorted TableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablerowsorter

I am trying to get the sorted `TableModel` of a `JTable` which is done by the following simple `regex` criteria:

```
try {
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sortRow = new TableRowSorter<>(testTable.getModel());
    testTable.setRowSorter(sortRow);
    String sortString = "Something";
    sortRow.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + sortString));
}
```

which will sort the data according to `sortString`.

But when I try to do the following :

```
try {
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sortRow = new TableRowSorter<>(testTable.getModel());
    // ....
    // previous code
    // ....
    TableModel tM = testTable.getModel();
    someOtherTestTable.setModel(tM); //<---Here
}
```

It provides me the `DefaultTableModel`. So, my question is this: **How do I get the sorted `TableModel` so that I can post to another `JTable`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`TableRowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) conditions the *view*, `JTable`; the *model*, `TableModel`, remains unchanged. If the underlying model of the `RowSorter` remains the same, you should be able apply the old `TableRowSorter` to the new `JTable` using [`setRowSorter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSorter-javax.swing.RowSorter-).

```
…
someOtherTestTable.setModel(tM);
someOtherTestTable.setRowSorter(sortRow);
```

Comment: Is there any way to alter the table model? May be discarding certain rows and then copying the content?

Comment: Alter content? No problem. Alter structure? Recreate the `TableRowSorter`.